# Recaptcha not working on Umbraco Contour Form

Tags: recaptcha, umbraco-contour

I have added Recaptcha field on Umbraco Contour. I am not able to submit the form. Recpatcha never validating.

Umbraco : 4.11.8
Contour: 3.0.7.0

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to remove Mandatory tag from Recaptcha, we have similar issue with Umbraco 4.11.10 and Contour version 3.0.17.
Once we unchecked Mandatory property of Recaptcha field we were able to submit form.